# compiling pcre 3.38 as 64bit on Solaris 10 - wrong ELF class

Tags: 64-bit, pcre, solaris-10

I am trying to compile pcre 3.38 on Solaris 10 as a 64 bit binary. It starts to compile, and then at some point stops complaining about "wrong ELF class", and indeed, it turns out that some object files created are 32bit - allthough most are 64 bit as desired.

Here is what I have done:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64
```

Then

```
make            
rm -f pcre_chartables.c
ln -s ./pcre_chartables.c.dist pcre_chartables.c
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/local/src/pcre-8.38'
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_byte_order.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_compile.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_config.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_dfa_exec.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_exec.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_fullinfo.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_get.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_globals.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_jit_compile.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_maketables.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_newline.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_ord2utf8.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_refcount.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_string_utils.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_study.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_tables.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_ucd.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_valid_utf8.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_version.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_xclass.lo
  CC       libpcre_la-pcre_chartables.lo
  CCLD     libpcre.la
  CC       libpcreposix_la-pcreposix.lo
  CCLD     libpcreposix.la
  CXX      libpcrecpp_la-pcrecpp.lo
  CXX      libpcrecpp_la-pcre_scanner.lo
  CXX      libpcrecpp_la-pcre_stringpiece.lo
  CXXLD    libpcrecpp.la
ld: fatal: file ./.libs/libpcre.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to .libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libpcrecpp.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/src/pcre-8.38'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Checking what was done so war, I see mostly 64 bit object files, but a few 32 bit ones, and I assume this is where the problem comes from:

```
file .libs/*
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_byte_order.o:     ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_chartables.o:     ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_compile.o:        ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_config.o: ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_dfa_exec.o:       ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_exec.o:   ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_fullinfo.o:       ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_get.o:    ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_globals.o:        ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_jit_compile.o:    ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_maketables.o:     ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_newline.o:        ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_ord2utf8.o:       ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_refcount.o:       ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_string_utils.o:   ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_study.o:  ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_tables.o: ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_ucd.o:    ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_valid_utf8.o:     ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_version.o:        ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre_la-pcre_xclass.o: ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcre.a:        current ar archive, 32-bit symbol table
.libs/libpcre.la:       ascii text
.libs/libpcre.lai:      ascii text
.libs/libpcre.so:       ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
.libs/libpcre.so.1:     ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
.libs/libpcre.so.1.2.6: ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
.libs/libpcrecpp_la-pcre_scanner.o:     ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable SPARC Version 1
.libs/libpcrecpp_la-pcre_stringpiece.o: ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable SPARC Version 1
.libs/libpcrecpp_la-pcrecpp.o:  ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable SPARC Version 1
.libs/libpcreposix_la-pcreposix.o:      ELF 64-bit MSB relocatable SPARCV9 Version 1
.libs/libpcreposix.a:   current ar archive, 32-bit symbol table
.libs/libpcreposix.la:  ascii text
.libs/libpcreposix.lai: ascii text
.libs/libpcreposix.so:  ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
.libs/libpcreposix.so.0:        ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
.libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.3:    ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
```

Its unclear to my why 32 bit binaries are even built, `CFLAGS=-m64` should take care of that.

Any idea how to debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

After a good night's sleep I found the solution. All 32 bit files have `cpp` in their name, a hint that they have to do with c++ support. Also the output of make for the 32 bit object files indicates the use of the c++ compiler by prefixing the line with `CXX`.

So there are two ways to fix the problem. In case c++ support is needed, the fix is to instruct the c++ compiler to generate 64 binaries, by adding `CXXFLAGS=-m64` to the configure line:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=-m64 CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64
```

The other option is to disable c++:

```
./configure --disable-cpp CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64
```

In my case I am not sure yet what I want, but here are they ways to fix this problem.